# Per the First Sale Doctrine, can I stream a DVD?

Tags: copyright

If I buy a DVD or Blu-ray, rent it to someone, and stream it to them for their personal/private use, is that permissible via the First Sale Doctrine?

Note that I'm not ripping the DVD or Blu-ray, but inserting the physical copy into the computer drive and streaming it to someone else.

Comment: You might consider asking if you can legally stream the DVD you bought.

Answer (score 4):

First sale doctrine is about selling something that you bought. You buy X, you pay your money, you have it and you own it. You don't want it anymore, so you sell it to me for money. Now you don't have X anymore, but I have it. That's what First Sale Doctrine is about: That you can buy something, and then you sell everything you have, including all the copies, to someone else.

What you are suggesting is absolutely nothing like that. You buy a DVD, you stream it, and after that you still have the DVD. That is absolutely not covered. What would be covered is that you sell the DVD to me, you hand over the DVD for cash, and you hand all the copies that you made over to me as well and destroy any traces that you still have. After the sale, you have my money and nothing else.

Comment: I think it should be "first sale" instead of "first use."

Comment: The doctrine is not just about selling; video rental stores are legal.

Comment: This is the right result, although I think  that the reason is not quite right. One of the rights that comes with copyright is a public performance right. When you stream, you violated that right. First sale doctrine does not give you a right to publicly perform the work you purchased, only a write to have that copy and use it and even rent or sell it to others.